# copy all elements from an array of array in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsmutablearray

i have received an array of elements from the server as web service responds. i am confused about how to handle it. i need to get those items in a single array.

```
(
    (
            (
        10,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        10,
        5,
        5,
        10,
        10,
        50
    )
)
 )
```

i need all objects in a single array.
so that it should look like

```
  (
    10,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    10,
    5,
    5,
    10,
    10,
    50
  )
```

Comment: Did you receive an array or an dictionary?

Comment: Did any of the solutions worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose **yourArray** is the array obtained from server as you have shown above, do this

```
NSArray *singleArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for your understanding for the format you got in your Array :
At the first index i.e 0 you got one array. And again in that array at index 0 you got your depth array.

**Simply access it like :**

```
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"final Array %@",finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to implement for loops if the result gave you an array with multiple arrays inside of it

```
NSArray *aryContents; // Your Input array
NSMutableArray *aryEditable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *adult in aryContents) {
    for (NSArray *child in adult) {
        [aryEditable addObjectsFromArray:child];
    }
}
NSArray *aryFullList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:aryEditable];
[aryEditable release];
```